# static method and data member in multi threaded app lower memory usage?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a multi threaded Java application which needs to use a library for getting timezones.The timezone library I'm using is [Timeshape](https://github.com/RomanIakovlev/timeshape)

According to its homepage it takes about 180 MB of memory, which is a big amount.

I'm trying to reduce memory usage as much as possible, so I have created the following class with the static method and have also made `TimeZoneEngine` into a static data member. Right now if each thread keeps recalling getTimezone then the same engine will be used and new ones will not created, is my assumption correct? Is having this static method and static data member a good way to save on memory?

```
public class TimeZone {

    static TimeZoneEngine engine = TimeZoneEngine.initialize();

    public static String getTimezone(double lat, double lon) {
        String timeZone = null;

        Optional<ZoneId> zoneId = engine.query(lat, lon);

        if (zoneId.isPresent()) {
            timeZone = zoneId.get().toString();
        }

        return timeZone;
    }
```

Comment: If `TimeZoneEngine.query()` is thread-safe then yes. If it is not then you save memory but introduce hard to find and debug concurrency bugs

Comment: If you going static, go to Singleton Pattern

Comment: `initialize()` is overloaded so if you're working with a limited lat/long range then that might reduce the memory usage.

Comment: Did you actually check if instantiation of multiple `TimeZoneEngine`s increaeses the memory footprint significantly? According to the library webpage, the memory usage is due to a need for "_heap memory to parse the geometry data and build index for the whole world_". It _could_ be the case that it is implemented in such a way that `TimeZoneEngine`s all use the same backing data and index. Furthermore, the webpage says that you can reduce the memory footprint by only loading parts of the world, so if you're only using this in a specific location, that'd be a way to save significant memory.

Answer (score 0):

Using a static method is a common way of reducing memory footprint. This approach has been codified in the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Another, non-static, approach is to pass a shared object to the constructor of an object that will use it. For example:

```
public class TimezoneService {
    public String getTimezone(double lat, double lon) { /* ... */ }
}

public class Foo {

    private final TimezoneService timezoneService;

    public Foo(TimezoneService timezoneService) {
        this.timezoneService = timezoneService;
    }

}
```

Note, though, that if multiple threads will use the shared object, some level of [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) or [concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) restriction is required.